# Using Executer service in multithreaded program

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using executer service for using multithreading. I have a large number of tasks. When I am submitting those tasks one by one using `executer.submit()` the heap space increasing and slowly slowly the java process becomes slow. How should I approach this problem?

For example: After getting all the data

```
while(resultset.hasnext())
{
I am thread objects here //
RunnableObject o = new RunnableObject(data);
executer.submit(o);
}
```

Comment: Question is too abstract without code.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, I understood that, you are retrieving results from database and assigning each recode to a thread, right ?

In this scenario, if you get 10 records, you will create 10 thread, but in the long run, if you get 1000 records, you can create 1000 threads right. this will make your application slower.

My solution is go for thread pools like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).